# select records between dates with regards to a specific item

Tags: mysql, sql

I posted a question days earlier about how I can query records and display results. it had to do with selecting records from a table between January and February with specific days eg. select records from 2nd January to 4th February. And this was the select statement I had which works.

```
SELECT *
FROM db_table
WHERE (day >= 2 and month = 'January')
   OR (day <= 4 and month = 'February')
```

I have been made aware its not the correct procedure to query records regarding dates and could be complex if 'years_column' is also needed.
but if my table has to do with records of items, this query will bring out all items within the chosen period.
if I want to select this date period with regards to a specific item, how do I do that. this was my sample query but it doesn't give the desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM db_table
WHERE (day >= 4 and month = 'January')
   OR (day <= 5 and month = 'February')and item='rice'
```

please any help.

Comment: If you're asked to find records between January and March, how will you handle that?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM db_table
WHERE (day >= 4 and month = 'January')
   OR (day <= 5 and month = 'April')  @Salman
   OR month IN ('February','March')

Comment: General advice is to use proper date data type instead of separate columns.

Comment: @RodneyNart see... it is clumsy!

Comment: yes I know bro, and I know using the ISO/MYSQL date format is the proper way. but for this type of query, I just wish there's  a way to extra filter by items too @Salman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM db_table
WHERE ((day >= 4 and month = 'January')
   OR (day <= 5 and month = 'February')) AND item='rice'
```

Explenation: `AND` is calculated befor `OR`  
Like in Arithmetics precedence `AND` is equivalent to * 
`OR` is equivalent to +

Comment: ohk so it means with the where statement, I must first query for the item before finding the records between the range of dates right @Siyon_DP

Comment: Your original shot brought you all records mitting the first criteria `day >= 4 and month = 'January'` including other products. It was impicitlly doing  `(day >= 4 and month = 'January')
   OR ((day <= 5 and month = 'February') AND item='rice')`

Comment: @rodney he's trying to tell you that your query, without brackets means find _any_ item in january - or - find rice in fabruary. Parenthesis fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM db_table
WHERE item='rice' and (day >= 4 and month = 'January')
   OR (day <= 5 and month = 'February')
```

thanks. I should have queried for the item first